# ajax upload image and send data

Tags: php, html, jquery, image-processing

I have html form with lot of textboxes, and three optional image uploads.

How can I make ajax:

1) Saves the pictures in the server folder [example: ./MyImages]

2) When pictures are saved, their URL's and all other textbox data is saved to mysql.

thank you

Comment: Very common task. A lot of eamples all over the Web.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp trying going through the content. you will be able to code on your own only!

Comment: i am not looking for ajax tutorial. i don't know how to upload pictures and save data at the same time using ajax. if you have solution for this, please link or tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Ajax Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to post the data and the files using ajax.

Then in your php file you can save the images into a directory, see : [move uploaded file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) then save the file names to your db.

So you can reach the url's using your website url, directory name and file name.